# c# picturebox size property loss after initialization

Tags: c#, size, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

In the c# windows form application designer window you can set picturebox size but this property is lost after initialization!

This is what designer generates with this size property:

```
this.pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(512, 424);
```

I created a mouseclick event using the designer and clicked the bottom right corner. The mouse click coordinates given me were 384, 344... Debugging the object also shows base.width / height = 384 / 344

Now I set the exact same property right after InitializeComponent();

And big wow the picturebox increased in size and now the same mouseclick generates the coordinates I want!

I can only assume that something is lost during initialization! The same line of code generated by designer and used after initialization behaves differently!

Whats up with that?

Is there any way to get the designer to actually initialize the picturebox properly and perhaps even show the real bounds in the design window?

Comment: `Required method for Designer support - do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.` it means Do not modify. If you want to change size make it in Designer, or if you want to change it programmaticaly - then in constructor, after `InitializeComponent();`. And don't be surprised if something not work. Especially when they told you not to modify it  manualy.

Comment: @Sergio Where did I ever write that I modified something in designer generated code? I set a property in designer GUI window (the one that generates the code) and then I copied a line from that code and used it after InitializeComponent(); and received different results.